# Grand Central Dispatch problems with dispatch_release

Tags: iphone, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I have a problem with a GCD solution I've made. I have a thread that runs in the background, it updates the application in a given interval. For this I use a timer.

However if the user wants to change this interval, I call

```
dispatch_source_cancel(timer);
```

Which is defined as

```
dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(timer, ^{
   dispatch_release(timer);
});
```

And then restart the the thread. When the interval is changed a second time the app crashes. Even though I do recreate the timer with a new interval.

I could avoid releasing the timer, but then I'll have memory leeks.

Any advice, what to do?

EDIT:
Timer is created like this

```
timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER,0,0, autoRefreshQueue);

if(!timer) {
    return;
}

dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, refreshRate * NSEC_PER_SEC), refreshRate * NSEC_PER_SEC, refreshRate * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, ^{
    //do work
});
```

Comment: How are you creating the timer?

Comment: hmm i prefer nsinvocation to GCD, you considered that?

Comment: What is nsinvocation? :)

Comment: I see no problem with your code. Why don't you post your crash log?

Comment: @Kazuki I don't think there is a problem with the code. The problem is when cancel the thread and then restart it immediatly after. Then I get error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the answer. dispatch_source_cancel doesn't cancel immediately, synchronously.

- man dispatch_source_cancel

  > The dispatch_source_cancel() function asynchronously cancels the dispatch source, preventing any further invocation of its event handler block. Cancellation does not interrupt a currently executing handler block (non-preemptive).

Thus, restarting the thread might invoke the blocks concurrently if autoRefreshQueue is Global Queue.

How did you restart the thread?

**EDITED:**

However there are no mentions of calling dispatch_source_set_timer twice (or more) for the same Dispatch Source in the references or the manuals, dispatch_source_set_timer in libdispatch/src/source.c seems ok for it. At least, as far as my test, there are no problem.

Thus, just call dispatch_source_set_timer for a new interval.

```
dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, refreshRate * NSEC_PER_SEC), refreshRate * NSEC_PER_SEC, refreshRate * NSEC_PER_SEC);
```

Comment: I do that by just calling the method that creates it. If it's not done synchronously i can understand why it crashes. Pheraps it's better to just reconfigure the timer?

Comment: Shouldn't I cancel the timers when the app resigns active?

Comment: No, you don't need to cancel the timers. it's automatically suspended when the app resigned active.